# Grouping and ordering class object based on there certain properties?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have `product` class which has `Description` property and have `3 product` objects:

```
Product product1 = new Product("This is bottom product");
Product product2 = new Product("This is top product");
Product product3 = new Product("This is medium product");

List<Product> lst = new List<Product>();
lst.Add(product1);
lst.Add(product2);
lst.Add(product3);
```

I want to re-arrange these objects so that all `products` with `description` of `top` comes on top and `product` with `description` as `bottom` comes at bottom.

```
var res = lst.Where(p => p.Desription == "This is top product")
                         .Concat(lst.Where(p => p.Desription == "This is medium product"))
                         .Concat(lst.Where(p => p.Desription == "This is bottom product")).ToList();
```

I have coded the above query to achieve this. This returns me correct results. But I am not sure if this is most efficient way to solve this problem?

Can someone suggest any alternative/performance-wise-better approach?

Note: I have simplified the problem here. Otherwise product has many more objects and properties.

Comment: What if you have 100 Products?

Comment: The logic i have would still work but i think it would be slow.

Comment: It's bad form to change the problem completely (aka a chameleon problem). Your edit pretty much invalidates everyone's answer not because they were wrong but because you fundamentally changed the problem.

Comment: You should really delete that question and post another one. Although the way you redefined the problem (*Grouping as they come*), looks like simple `GroupBy` followed by `SelectMany` will be sufficient.

Comment: yes. i will do that. But do you think GroupBy followed by SelectMany would be better than using Where.Concat.Concat I am using now?

Comment: Yes, it will in the general case. Your current code is O(N * M) (N=source.Count, M=distinct property values count) while the other will be O(N)

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

The better solution than comparer(quicker):

```
 public enum ProductType
    {
        Bottom=0,
        Medium,
        Top,
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public ProductType Type { get; set; }
        //the rest of properties here
    }

 var list = new List<Product>();
 var orderedList = list.OrderBy(x => (int)x.Type).ToList();
```

If you don't want to add anything to the existing class, maybe wrap it or extend?

Comment: @FirstStep Here you are

Comment: Nice solution, +1

Answer (score 1):

Given this in your question:

```
var res = lst.Where(p => p.Desription == "This is top product")
                         .Concat(lst.Where(p => p.Desription == "This is medium product"))
                         .Concat(lst.Where(p => p.Desription == "This is bottom product")).ToList();
```

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
var res = lst.OrderBy(p => p.Desription);
```

I'd like to point out that your variable for "Description" is misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDic = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"top", 1},
    {"medium", 2},
    {"bottom", 3}
};
var res = lst.OrderBy(c => myDic[c.Desription.Split(' ')[2]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, if you know each description will only contain the specific wording 'top', 'bottom', 'medium' and **only one** of those:

```
List<Product> res = new List<Product>();
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count(); i++)
{
    res.AddRange(lst.Where(p => p.Desription.Contains("top").ToList());
    res.AddRange(lst.Where(p => p.Desription.Contains("medium").ToList());
    res.AddRange(lst.Where(p => p.Desription.Contains("bottom").ToList());
}
```

I use `AddRange` instead of `Add` since there may be multiple 'top', 'medium' or 'bottom' products.

Also it won't work if the descriptions contain 'top' and 'bottom' in the same sentence, 'top' and 'medium', etc.